# Security configuration with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm a beginner, I want to code the password when adding users but there is an error (`@Bean`).

```
Error:

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    

Description:

Field passwordEncoder in com.example.demo.service.UsersService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

My code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UsersService userService;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        http.csrf().disable() //TODO implement csrf
        .cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/add-users").permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```java
public class UsersService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository repo;
    
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        
    public Users save(Users u) {
        String encodpass=passwordEncoder.encode(u.getPassword());
        String confpass=passwordEncoder.encode(u.getConfirmepass());
        u.setConfirmpass(confpass);
        u.setPassword(encodpass);
        u.setLock(false);
        u.setEnable(true);
        return repo.save(u);
    }
}

    @RestController  
    public class UsersController {
        @Autowired 
        private UsersService service;
        @PostMapping("/add-users")
        public Users add(@RequestBody Users u) {
            return service.save(u);}
```

Comment: The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' in your configuration.

Comment: Field passwordEncoder in com.example.demo.service.UsersService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' that could not be found.

Comment: Add `@Service` annotation to your `UsersServce` class so that it is managed by Spring and so that you can autowire fields. Then, where is your `save()` method called ? As you implement `UserDetailsService` you must override the `loadUserByUsername()` method, is it called from there ?

Comment: yes i add @Service, and i override the loadUserByUsername(),  save is called from a controller

Comment: why after configuring spring security if I try to access with postman I always get a 403 response unauthorized ?

Comment: Please provide the code showing how you call that method from your controller. Maybe you instantiate your `UsersService` with the `new` operator ? In that case `@Autowired` would be just ignored. As a test, try to simply autowire `passwordEncoder` in your controller and do the stuff there instead of calling your method in `UsersService`, it should work.

Comment: @Yann39 you can see controller code , pleez can you tell me why i get 401 response with postman when i use methode post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `SecurityConfiguration` you are injecting `UsersService`, and the `UserService` bean depends on a bean of type `PasswordEncoder` that has not been created yet.

I'll simplify your configuration by using a more ellegant way of configuring Spring Security:

```java
@Configuration
//your other annotations
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain app(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/add-users").permitAll()
        .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

And that's it, you don't really need the `AuthenticationManager` bean unless you are actually using it. In case that you need it, you can create it like this:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UsersService usersService) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(usersService);
    ProviderManager manager = new ProviderManager(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    return manager;
}
```

I apologize for any compilation error beforehand because I wrote this from a phone.

Answer (score -1):

add @Service annotation to UserService class. also add @EnableWebSecurity to config class.

Comment: I did that but the same problem

Comment: can u create a git repo of your project and send me the link? i can finish it much faster that way.

Comment: He already uses `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`. He may not need `@EnableWebSecurity`, it is not a requirement and is probably not the reason of the error.

Comment: why after configuring spring security if I try to access with postman I always get a 403 response unauthorized ?